# Why are my web pages zoomed in when I open them in Opera Mobile?

Tags: php, html, mobile, opera-mini, opera-mobile

I am developing a mobile version of web pages. I am testing with a Symbian phone with two browsers. The default browser is working properly but I am having problem with Opera Mobile.

Every time a page loads, it loads zoomed in rather than being fit the screen. This even happens in a simple page like this:

```
    <?php
        echo    "<p>Guys I am developing a mobile version web pages, I am testing with a symbian phone with two browsers. The default browser is working properly but I am having problem with Opera Mibile, each time it loads a page a page that is zoomed in - instead of loading a page that just fits the screan. even a simple page like this one</P>
                <p>Is there anything i should include in the in my code to tell it to load a page that needs not to be zoomed. Will greatly apreciated, have spend almost the whole day on google?</p>";
    ?>
```

**Is there any way to make the pages fit to the screen when I load them** rather than having them load zoomed in?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your `<head>` element: `<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport' />`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanx once again, had noticed, am still new on this platform